# Как создать мобильную версию сайта

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Мне нужно создать мобильную версию сайта, которая кардинально отличается от компьютерной по верстке и css. Это не просто адаптивный шаблон. Вопрос в том, как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать медиа запросы к вашим стилям. Ознакомьтесь с данным гайдом и вы сможете немного разобраться в этом направлении: https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам требуется поменять на мобильном именно верстку, то есть HTML-разметку, то вы можете поместить ее в отдельный блок, например для хедера (аналогично - для прочих крупных блоков, которые будут отличатьтся от десктопной версии). Этот блок будет скрываться на больших разрешениях через свойство display: none, и показываться на мобильных через display: block. Соответственно, блок с десктопной версией также придется обернуть в обертку, скрывать его на мобильных и показывать на десктопе.

```css
@media  screen and (min-width: 525px) {
  .header-pc {
    display: block
  }
  .header-mobile {
    display: none
  }
}

@media  screen and (max-width: 525px) {
  .header-pc {
    display: none
  }
  .header-mobile {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-pc">Header On PC</div>
<div class="header-mobile">Header on Mobile</div>
```

Однако это достаточно "костыльное" и некрасивое решение. Правильнее было бы изначально построить разметку страницы так, чтобы в зависимости от разрешения часть блоков можно было скрыть, а часть - расположить на странице иначе. В этом смысл адаптива и его отличие от респонсива: адаптивная страница перестраивает свою структуру средствами CSS в зависимости от разрешения экрана, то есть это именно, как вы говорите, кардинально различающиеся страницы визуально, хотя их разметка остается неизменной на всех разрешениях.

CSS для мобильных назначаетcя через [медиазапросы](https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/) либо с использованием css-фреймворков вроде [Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-4.ru/).

Answer (score 1):

Наверняка встречали *поддомены* сайтов, к примеру `vk.com`, а есть `m.vk.com`. При переходе на сайт с *поддоменом* `m.vk.com` у вас открывается "мобильная версия" сайта. Что вам нужно чтобы реализовать данный функционал:

- Правильная маршрутизация на веб-сервере, который вы используете.
- Лучше всего создать отдельный проект, если вы хотите сделать полностью отличную стилизацию от "родительского сайта".
- Продумать дизайн мобильной версии
- Собрать проект.
- Настроить все *редиректы*, если веб-сервер обнаруживает что это **мобильное устройство**, к примеру, вы заходите с телефона на сайт `vk.com`, установленный и **правильно настроенный** веб-сервер перенаправляет вас на мобильную версию(ваш *поддомен*) `m.vk.com`, на **desktop** такого происходить **не должно**.

Answer (score -1):

Я [согласен с Лебедевым](https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/177/) в этом вопросе

> Самая большая глупость на свете — создание отдельных мобильных
>   версий сайтов.
>
> Возможно, на сорок пятом этаже в переговорной крупного банка
>   красивый рассказ о преимуществах мобильной версии звучит убедительно.
>
> — Смотрите! Мы берем обычный айфон. Заходим на ваш сайт. И что
>   видим? Обычный сайт? Это же ужасно. Смотрите, как это работает у банка
>   N. У них открывается специально разработанная мобильная версия! Из
>   трех кнопок!
>
> — Мари-Изабель, подпишите контракт с молодыми людьми.
>
> Еще раз повторим для невнимательно прочитавших первое предложение:
>   самая большая глупость на свете — создание отдельных мобильных версий
>   сайтов.
>
> Делать мобильные версии сайтов есть смысл только за деньги тех,
>   кому некуда деньги девать.
>
> Чем хорош современный смартфон? Тем, что это практически
>   полноценный компьютер. Он умеет все. В том числе — нормально
>   показывать сайты. Спрашивается, если телефон нормально показывает
>   сайт, зачем что-то еще изобретать? Через телефон все отлично видно.
>
> В качестве доказательства того, что мобильные версии сайтов никому
>   не нужны, можно привести в пример компанию «Эппл». Они все это
>   придумали, сделали айфоны и айпады. И их собственный сайт открывается
>   на всех их устройствах так же, как на любом обычном компьютере. Безо
>   всяких мобильных версий.

Ну а если уж нужно как-то отдельно работать через смартфоны, то нужно писать под них приложения, работающие с API ресурса

Comment: Что это за бред? Верстка под мобилки затронута в данном вопросе, а не апи и отдельное приложение. Удобно серфить веб-сайт если он адаптирован и читабилен. Вы смотрели статистику посещений вебсайтов с мобильных устройств? Адаптация важный фактор, и дело далеко не в апи и другом приложении. Upd: если автор, которого вы процитировали действительно говорит о подобных вещах, ему стоит перестать нести чушь. Я не думаю что это какой-то большой нейм чтобы слушать его и воспринимать бред в заправду. Его некомпетентность уже была доказана в его же словах. Удачи освоить меди запросы :^

Comment: Возможно, тут речь идет про WAP-версии, а не адаптив?

Comment: о, wap ещё жив разве? о0

Comment: При чем тут API и мобильная версия сайта, совершенно два разных предназначения.